# Importing a PostGIS geometry type into Python as a geometry type from Shapely?

Tags: python, postgresql, gis, postgis, shapely

So I have a situation where I have a ton of Linestrings of a broken up route, where I need to Union them together using Shapely's LineMerge or Union OR PostGIS ST_Union.

My idea right now is to use Shapely to import the [Linestrings](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#geometric-objects) as Geometry types. Union them or merge them using Shapely, and then export back to a results table in the database.

However, the geometry type in the PostGIS database is just a bunch of gibberish. Like...

```
01020000020e61000....
```

How can I translate this from the database to a Python geometry type using Shapely, do some manipulations, and then export it back to a database?

Currently this is my code, its just importing that geom object string from the database right now and throwing errors because it isn't a Geometry type.

```
def create_shortest_route_geom(shortest_routes):
    conn = connect_to_database()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    shortest_route_geoms = []
    for route in shortest_routes:
        source = str(int(route[1]))
        target = str(int(route[2]))
        query = 'SELECT the_geom FROM public.ways WHERE target_osm = ' + target + ' AND source_osm = ' + source + ' OR target_osm = ' + source + ' AND source_osm = ' + target + ';'
        cur.execute(query)
        total_geom = cur.fetchone()
        for index, node in enumerate(route):
            try:
                source = str(int(node))
                target = str(int(route[index + 1]))
                query = 'SELECT the_geom FROM public.ways WHERE target_osm = ' + target + ' AND source_osm = ' + source + ' OR target_osm = ' + source + ' AND source_osm = ' + target + ';'
                cur.execute(query)
                geom = cur.fetchone()
                query = "SELECT ST_Union("+str(geom[0])+","+str(total_geom[0])+")"
                cur.execute(query)
                total_geom = cur.fetchone()
            except IndexError:
                print "Last element"
        shortest_route_geoms.insert(total_geom)
    return shortest_route_geoms
```

EDIT: [I may have found my answer here, looking more into it and will update my question with an answer if I figure this out.](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#interoperation)

Comment: Instead of string concatenating values to SQL queries please use placeholders. Makes for more readable code, removes the need to manually "handle" quoting, and mitigates risk of injections, in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Shapely already has libraries for this specific problem.](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#interoperation)

PostGIS stores the geometries as HEX values. Use Shapely's loads function to load this with the parameter of hex=True.

Specifically...

```
geom = shapely.wkb.loads(hex_geom[0], hex=True)
```

Don't use PostGIS ST_Union, cause you have to dump and load over and over for this to work. Shapely has that configured as well with [linemerge](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#shapely.ops.linemerge)